# Initialise nothing variables in Julia

Tags: julia

How to write initialisation for variable that could be nothing in Julia?

```
id = nothing
title = "Something"
hash  = "31114"

id = id || title || hash # Not working
```

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? What is your exact intended output?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. If you want to know `id` is meaningfully defined, you should use `isdefined`. If you want to differentiate between nothing and the "nothing" value, you should use `Some(nothing)`. If you're trying to perform a boolean test, you should choose types that convert readily to booleans.

Comment: With regard to the accepted answer, note the difference between `something( nothing, 0 )` and `something( Some(nothing), 0 )`. If "nothing" is a legitimate value in your dataset then you need to be aware of it. The question sounds a bit like an XY solution looking for a problem. Whatever you're doing it sounds like you'd be better off wrapping your triplet in some sort of structure (e.g. a Dict or Dataframe) and checking for missing values etc.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou it throws an error if you try to execute it. It's a common construct in JS to initialize variables, I was looking for something similar in Julia. `something` solves the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`something`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/some.jl#L92) will return the first value that does not equal `nothing`. It supports a variable number of arguments:

```
julia> something(0, nothing)
0

julia> something(nothing, "foo")
"foo"

julia> something(nothing, nothing, 1)
1
```

You can use it to set the default value for a variable:

```
x = something(x, DEFAULT_VALUE)
```

Your example can use:

```
julia> id = nothing

julia> title = "Something"
"Something"

julia> hash  = "31114"
"31114"

julia> id = something(id, title, hash)
"Something"
```

Comment: Note that in this case `missing` would likely be a better fit..

Comment: `missing` is not necessarily better for this pattern. On the contrary, if you don't want the uninitialized value to propagate silently, then `nothing` is the right choice.